# Making a ENTER button for my banking app

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I'm trying to make a log in screen which has 10 buttons 0-10 and only accepts 4 digits. I have stored some variables called PIN0-PIN03 which holds a int value. I want the user to enter 4 digit pin and if it matches the values stored in the variables PIN0-PIN03 a name will appear.

I have done the button and everything I just need help with this ENTER button

the code I used for the ENTER button is:

```
int pin = 0000;
int PIN0 = 1234; // if user enters this value the program will start executing the if statments.
int PIN1 = 2345;
int PIN2 = 3456;
int PIN3 = 4567;\\

if (pin == PIN0){

System.out.println("Hi Muhannad");
if (pin == PIN0){ // if user enters PIN0 it will display the below message

System.out.println("Hi Muhannad");
}

if( pin == PIN1){
System.out.println("Hi Mo");
}

if( pin == PIN2){
System.out.println("Hi Mahir");
}

if( pin == PIN3){


System.out.println("Hi Gawi");
}

if(pin != PIN0 || pin != PIN1 || pin != PIN2 || pin != PIN3){
System.out.println("Incorrect pin try again!");  // if user enters anything that doesn't match any of the variables values the "Incorrect pin try again" will apear. 
}
```

I'm I doing this right?

please help this is a project I started in my own time to create an app similar to banking apps.

Code for the buttons:

```
private void buttonOneActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
if(evt.getSource() == buttonOne){
            if(jTextField1.getText().length() < 4){
                if(clearField == 1){
                    jTextField1.setText("0");
                    clearField = 0;
                } else{
                    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText() + "1");
                }
            }
}
}                                         

private void buttonTwoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
if(evt.getSource() == buttonTwo){
            if(jTextField1.getText().length() < 4){
                if(clearField == 1){
                    jTextField1.setText("2");
                    clearField = 0;
                } else{
                    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText() + "2");
                }
            }
}
}                                         

private void buttonThreeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
if(evt.getSource() == buttonThree){
            if(jTextField1.getText().length() < 4){
                if(clearField == 1){
                    jTextField1.setText("3");
                    clearField = 0;
                } else{
                    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText() + "3");
                }
            }
}
}                                           

private void buttonFourActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
if(evt.getSource() == buttonFour){
            if(jTextField1.getText().length() < 4){
                if(clearField == 1){
                    jTextField1.setText("4");
                    clearField = 0;
                } else{
                    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText() + "4");
                }
            }
}
}                                          

private void buttonFiveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
if(evt.getSource() == buttonFive){
            if(jTextField1.getText().length() < 4){
                if(clearField == 1){
                    jTextField1.setText("5");
                    clearField = 0;
                } else{
                    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText() + "5");
                }
            }
}
}                                          

private void buttonSixActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
if(evt.getSource() == buttonSix){
            if(jTextField1.getText().length() < 4){
                if(clearField == 1){
                    jTextField1.setText("6");
                    clearField = 0;
                } else{
                    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText() + "6");
                }
            }
}// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                         

private void buttonSevenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
if(evt.getSource() == buttonSeven){
            if(jTextField1.getText().length() < 4){
                if(clearField == 1){
                    jTextField1.setText("7");
                    clearField = 0;
                } else{
                    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText() + "7");
                }
            }
}
}                                           

private void buttonEightActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
if(evt.getSource() == buttonEight){
            if(jTextField1.getText().length() < 4){
                if(clearField == 1){
                    jTextField1.setText("8");
                    clearField = 0;
                } else{
                    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText() + "8");
                }
            }
}
}                                           

private void buttonNineActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
if(evt.getSource() == buttonNine){
            if(jTextField1.getText().length() < 4){
                if(clearField == 1){
                    jTextField1.setText("9");
                    clearField = 0;
                } else{
                    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText() + "9");
                }
            }
}
}                                          

private void buttonZeroActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
if(evt.getSource() == buttonZero){
            if(jTextField1.getText().length() < 4){
                if(clearField == 1){
                    jTextField1.setText("0");
                    clearField = 0;
                } else{
                    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText() + "0");
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: So you want it to run through this code when the user presses enter on their keyboard?

Comment: Though unrelatednto your question, your last if statement contains a small error. It should read pin != PIN1

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper yes I want it to do just that however when I run the code even when I enter the right pin numbers I still get "Incorrect pin try again". Why's that I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @MrHug thanks for pointing that out! i completely missed that

Comment: Ah, well in that case, show how your code is handling input, where does the user get to type in their input? That's the code we need to solve this problem

Comment: Just uploaded my buttons codes Mr @DreadHeadedDeveloper

Comment: You've got the wrong logical expression in your last statement.  Your intent would be better expressed as a `switch` statement (or better yet, a proper `Map<int,String>`).  See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/vermiculus/12b8e64ff3222ca6c129) for an example of what this might look like as a `switch` statement.  As an aside, it'd be better to create a full gist for others to look at and run if they wish.  You may be interested in the `gist` Ruby gem to ease uploading it.

Comment: I'll be using gist to upload my code to make it easier for others to check my codes thanks for letting me know... also I tried your method and I get "constant expression required" @SeanAllred

Comment: Try the updated gist.  It's been a while since I've done Java.

Comment: You are checking 2 times `if (pin == PIN0)` for some reason.

Comment: (1) What is `clearField`? (2) If you use buttons for entering numbers then use a button for the "Enter" command. Don't mix the keyboard in this.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give a lot of information as to how your code should work, but here is an example:

```
public class Bank extends JFrame {

    static final int PIN0 = 1234;
    static final int PIN1 = 2345;
    static final int PIN2 = 3456;
    static final int PIN3 = 4567;

    JTextField tf = new JTextField();

    public Bank() {

        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 3));

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            JButton button = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
            button.addActionListener(new NumberAction(i));
            buttonsPanel.add(button);
        }

        JButton enterButton = new JButton("Enter");
        enterButton.addActionListener(new EnterAction());

        getContentPane().add(tf, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        getContentPane().add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(enterButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class NumberAction extends AbstractAction {

        int i;

        NumberAction(int i) {

            this.i = i;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (tf.getText().length() < 4)
                tf.setText(tf.getText() + i);
        }
    }

    class EnterAction extends AbstractAction {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            switch (Integer.parseInt(tf.getText())) {
                case PIN0:
                    System.out.println("Hi 0");
                    break;
                case PIN1:
                    System.out.println("Hi 1");
                    break;
                case PIN2:
                    System.out.println("Hi 2");
                    break;
                case PIN3:
                    System.out.println("Hi 3");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Incorrect pin try again!");
            }

            tf.setText("");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new Bank();
    }
}
```